# Create fake data based on country or locale using roboframework-faker library

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, faker

I'm trying to assign some profile values to robot variables, I need basic data such FN, LN, Country, Language, Locale, Address, Phone, ZipCode based on either CountryCode or locale. Unfortunately I'm unable to do so, it generates random values every time.

for example, If I pass US as country or en_US as locale, I need all data for US (locale specific)

below is my test, please tell me how to initiate localization on robot level

````
*** Settings ***
Library  FakerLibrary  locale=en_US

*** Test Cases ***
Faker-001 Testing faker library
    [Tags]  faker
    ${Fname}=  FakerLibrary.first_name
    ${Lname}=  FakerLibrary.first_name
    ${Phone}=  FakerLibrary.phone_number
    ${address}=  FakerLibrary.address
    ${country}=  FakerLibrary.country
    ${locale}=  FakerLibrary.locale
    ${Language_code} =  FakerLibrary.Language_code
    ${email}=  FakerLibrary.email
    ${profile} =  catenate
    ...              ${\n}=====================
    ...              ${\n} FN: ${Fname}
    ...              ${\n} LN: ${Lname}
    ...              ${\n} Phone: ${Phone}
    ...              ${\n} Address: ${address}
    ...              ${\n} Country: ${country}
    ...              ${\n} Locale: ${locale}
    ...              ${\n} Language: ${Language_code}
    ...              ${\n} Email: ${email}
    ...              ${\n}=====================
    Log To Console  ${profile}```

Result:
``` FN: Thomas 
 LN: Tiffany 
 Phone: 500.259.1890 
 Address: Unit 9041 Box 5378
DPO AP 09359 
 Country: Argentina 
 Locale: br_FR 
 Language: ca 
 Email: donna60@yahoo.com```
````

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Faker Library documentation](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/fakerclass.html#examples)? You should be able to implement similar thing in the Robot script or then make a Python script to provide the required data from the library.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm looking more robot level so i can inject in to variables directly. I also tried using .py script. but what I need is, when i give locale for example 'de-DE', I need all data from Germany in German transations

Comment: for example: 
```fake = Faker('de-DE')
fake.random.seed()
print('-------------------')
print(fake.locales)
print(fake.current_country())
print(fake.current_country_code())
print(fake.language_code())
print(fake.first_name())
print(fake.last_name())
print(fake.address())
print(fake.postcode())
print(fake.phone_number())
print('----------------')```

I need phone number, addresses, postal code language code from Germany,  
it currently outputs random data.
----------
```['de_DE']
Germany
DE
as
Arnfried
Henschel
Jockelgasse 910
82122 Burglengenfeld
88226
06876 443292```